# Is there a solution to convert an ImageSource to an Android Bitmap and vice-versa in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bitmap, imagesource

I'm currently working on an application that modifies a picture that is currently located in the PCL project. And I'm currently having trouble with converting the DataTypes.

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can convert an ImageSource to a bitmap. I've read some answers on the internet but they didn't seem to work for me.

I call the platform-specific code with a DependencyService and pass the ImageSource as a parameter.

The function signature looks like this:

```cs
        public ImageSource BlurImage(ImageSource ImageSource)
        {

            return null;
        }
```

This function should Create a bitmap from the ImageSource first and once all the logic has been done it should convert back to an ImageSource.

Can someone explain to me how I should convert ImageSource to bitmap and vice-versa?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: What is your `imageSource`, lengthy `string` or file like .png?

Comment: @CGPA6.4 imageSource is an ImageSource DateType. I retrieve this from Image.Source in the PCL project before I call the platform depended code

Comment: how did you create the ImageSource in the first place?  You should use that original image, not the ImageSource

Comment: The original Image is in the PCL project as resource and is used like this:

```csharp
            blurImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Guassian.Assets.Images.Test.JPG");
```

This blurImage is used in Xaml and the source is later passed as a argument

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below function to convert `ImageSource` to `Bitmap`:

```
 private async Task<Bitmap> GetImageFromImageSource(ImageSource imageSource, Context context)
    {
        IImageSourceHandler handler;

        if (imageSource is FileImageSource)
        {
            handler = new FileImageSourceHandler();
        }
        else if (imageSource is StreamImageSource)
        {
            handler = new StreamImagesourceHandler(); // sic
        }
        else if (imageSource is UriImageSource)
        {
            handler = new ImageLoaderSourceHandler(); // sic
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        var originalBitmap = await handler.LoadImageAsync(imageSource, context);         

        return originalBitmap;
    }
```

And the Next one for `Bitmap` to `ImageSource`:

```
public async Task<ImageSource> GetBytesFromImage(Bitmap bitmap)
 {
    ImageSource imgSource;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream); // You can change the compression asper your understanding
        imgSource=ImageSource.FromStream(stream);
    }
   return imgSource;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I'll try this out tomorrow and probably mark this as solved

Comment: Sure no problem let me know if something does not work

Comment: It does work, More information here : https://medium.com/@hakimgulamali88/a-helper-for-converting-a-xamarin-forms-imagesource-to-the-respective-native-images-56a5aaf98156